# PDF format generated with no data shown in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am trying to generate a report in *iReport* with three row groups, which results in huge amount of data being retrieved from database. I have set enough page height to get all data in one sheet in Excel and HTML formats, but the PDF format generated is blank. 5 pages are being generated but they are not showing any data. When I reduce the page height to one fourth, data is displayed but with more no of sheets report. So I am unable to figure out if there is a problem with my report or with some properties which obviously I would need to fix.

My template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="fte_summary_main_link" language="groovy" pageWidth="4000" pageHeight="40000" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="4000" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="b36dcea3-b438-417d-a4b4-77de45543aa9">
    <property name="setContentLength" value="outputStream_.toByteArray().length"/>
    <parameter name="p_deal_detail_id" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="p_tower_id" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\report_suchita\\FTE Summary\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="DUMMY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="40000">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="f9f5259a-e52a-445f-b00e-0b0f03696447" x="0" y="0" width="4000" height="10000"/>
                <subreportParameter name="deal_Detail_Id">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{p_deal_detail_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="tower_Id">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{p_tower_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "FTE_SUMMAR_SUBTOWER_WISE.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="40000">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="febf5345-b2f8-4afe-b5ed-db283ef7464c" x="0" y="0" width="4000" height="10000"/>
                <subreportParameter name="p_deal_detai_id">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{p_deal_detail_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="p_tower_id">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{p_tower_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "report6.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="40000">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="11cec18f-675a-4a39-94bc-3fb584ae5c2a" x="0" y="0" width="4000" height="10000"/>
                <subreportParameter name="dealDetailId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{p_deal_detail_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="towerId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{p_tower_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "FTE Summary GNDM view.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="40000">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="23cd3095-0210-49e0-8659-60d7b16b7b5e" x="0" y="0" width="4000" height="10000"/>
                <subreportParameter name="dealDetailId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{p_deal_detail_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="towerId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{p_tower_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "FTE Summary Subtower-Location Type-LocationWise Report.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <summary>
        <band height="40000">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement uuid="01617f32-cc93-43ab-b155-c923a7cd0ae9" x="0" y="0" width="4000" height="10000"/>
                <subreportParameter name="towerId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{p_tower_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="dealDetailId">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{p_deal_detail_id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "FTE Summary-Location Type Location Type.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: You should post *jrxml* file

Comment: I have posted my jrxml above

Comment: I am trying to generate a report in iReport with three row groups, which results in huge amount of data being retrieved from database. I have set enough page height to get all data in one sheet in Excel and HTML formats, but the PDF format generated is blank. 5 pages are being generated but they are not showing any data.
When I reduce the page height to one fourth, data is displayed but with more no of sheets http://jasperreports. So I am unable to figure out if there is a problem with my report or with some properties which obviously I would need to fix.

Comment: Somehow the question got replaced.Sorry for that. I have added the question in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set band height to much high.You just need to set band height as minimum as possible to add all pallate in particular field. Also you just need to set positionType float for subreport and you can set it at any size like 15,20 etc.also you can add many subreport in one detail band.

```
<detail>
<band>
<subreport>
            <reportElement uuid="de20448b-1374-42bd-a65c-85e71a50d30d" positionType="Float" x="170" y="180" width="345" height="15"/>

            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{ListName})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["path/to/subreport"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
<subreport>
            <reportElement uuid="de20448b-1374-42bd-a65c-85e71a50d30d" positionType="Float" x="170" y="180" width="345" height="15"/>
            <subreportParameter name="imagePathInSubreport">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{imagePathInTemplate12}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{resumeList})]]></dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["/home/jft/workspace/CvSurgeon/CvSurgeon/web-app/report/template12/profile.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
</band>
</detail>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, but still the pdf generated is blank.Other two formats,namely HTML and Excel are all fine.Just unable to understand the reason for it.

Comment: Which version of ireport and jasper report you use?

Comment: Are you using ireport preview to generate pdf or using some action or controller code. Also Have you compiled jasper file of your subreport?

Comment: iReport preview for generation of pdf.